# How to add a middleware in all applications hosted in IIS

Tags: .net-core, iis, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm running more than 10 dotnet core applications in IIS. I need to add a middleware in all those applications. How can I add the middleware in all the applications hosted in my IIS without touching the application code? I'm not allowed to change the code and redeploy each application in IIS. Is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @Zader, how is the middleware like? What's your scenario?

Comment: I implemented the middleware to print all the incoming requests based on some conditions. I don't want to use IIS logs.

Answer (score 0):

> I implemented the middleware to print all the incoming requests based on some conditions. I don't want to use IIS logs

According to your description, I suggest you could consider writing a customer module to achieve your requirement.

An HTTP module is called on every request in response to the BeginRequest and EndRequest events. As a result, the module runs before and after a request is processed.

You could check the request at these module and write logs into it.  More details about how to write httpmodule, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms227673(v=vs.100)).

Comment: Thanks. I tried HttpModule and it works fine for dotnet framework applications. But it seems not working for dotnet core applications. Can I use HttpModule for dotnet core applications hosted in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, there is non-code based way to wire up middleware. You need to change all 10 applications. There's one feature that may be interesting though to look at [IHostingStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0) as a way to provide cross cutting auto wire up for common application logic.